# Does a trailing plus sign on the left make sense in SASS

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I came across a piece of code in SASS similar to

```css
.foo {
    + .someClass {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
}
```

Plus sign obviously has a function of an adjacent combinator. Shouldn't it be written as `& + .someClass`? Is it still valid if the left of the operator is blank? Does it select `.someClass` adjacent to `.foo` or what else could be intended? Is it a good practice to omit `&` provided that it is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While valid, adding an ampersand before the [combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) is not necessary at all. The ampersand is only needed for [attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp), [pseudo classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp), and [pseudo elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp), because the real difference between those using `&` and those not (in theory) is the space in the output. [Here's](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) a good article on this.